# filtering product collection on "is_salable"

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I would like to filter a product collection to show only items that are in stock.  I thought this would be easy given that there's an attribute called 'is_salable' that is 1 (true) if it's in stock, 0 (false) if not.  But no matter what I do, it doesn't work.  Further, it seems to halt the execution of the query before it finishes.

Here's some sample code:

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute', true);
//So far, so good...filtering on 'my_attribute' works!
Mage::Log("select: " . $this->_productCollection->getSelect());
//Successfully outputs the SQL query
$this->_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_salable', '1');
Mage::Log("select: " . $this->_productCollection->getSelect());
//does NOT output any query...it's like it died trying
```

So what am I doing wrong?  I've tried 'addFieldToFilter', 'addAttributeToFilter', and miscellaneous other queries, such as: `addFieldToFilter('is_salable', array('eq' => true))`, etc...

Anyone know how to do this?  If 'is_salable' is not the answer, all I need to do is filter out products that are not in stock...so whatever works to do that would be fine :)

Thanks!

Comment: Quick tip: Sometimes a select object cannot be dumped correctly, at least not without running out of memory. Casting it to string is more reliable... `(string)$this->getProductCollection()->getSelect()`

Comment: The `__toString()` method will automatically be called when concatenating with a string (since PHP 5.2, see [the docs](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring))

Comment: @jongosi actually the function name is ```isSalable``` as defined in **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product** so your comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no `is_salable` attribute in the product so it will rise an exception. If you want to display only products that are in stock, use this stock model `addInStockFilterToCollection` method:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
```

Comment: Thanks, @ivan-chepurnyi!  That worked great!  However, I'm still a bit confused.  If I loop through the products in the collection and print out each one, the product contains an 'attribute' called 'is_salable'.  Is that a generated element that can't be filtered on?  Is that why it's different than other filterable attributes?

Comment: Checkout at the isSalable() funciton on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.  A lot of times regular ol' attributes don't have a specific method.  In this case looks like it calls the isSalable() function on yet another class, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple (or Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped or Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable depending on the product type)

Comment: @BrianVPS `is_salable` property in product list is an indexed value of possible `isSalable` method call. The result of `isSalable` method call can be different depends on product type and logic defined in `Mage_CatalogInventory` module observers. Also it may be different from the actual method call, if during the custom module development, the appropriate indexes wasn't customized as well.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'm new to SO so don't know the protocol :)  I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this as well...

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gteq' => 1))->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
```

> addFieldFilter ('qty',array('gteq'
>   =>1))

get all products collection that have a stock of 1 or greater, you can put any number here according to your needs

> addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple')

filter by simple products

Comment: This solution will not work in case that you're not managing your stock levels in Magento and use just in/out of stock flags as you dont need to specify the quantity to have the product visible on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the problem that isSaleable() always returns false on my products, the problem was that I was getting the collection but didn't add the attribute price to the collection. 
In the isSaleable() function there is a check to make sure the price isn't 0, it needs the price attribute to check that so:

Changing:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->addUrlRewrite();
```

To:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->addUrlRewrite();
```

Did the trick :)

Comment: What about out of stock products? Their price is not zero, yet they are not saleable.