# Magento- issaleable filter

Tags: magento, collections

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

puts a filter and shows the products which are in stock, But always show configurable products-even when they are out of stock(AS they are always in stock but isSaleable gets false when their associated products gets over.) So How can I apply a IsSaleable filter on a product collection? (can it be done directly on a product collection without iterating through the collection.
Out of stock means inventory is over.

Comment: Not quite certain about what your asking, but you might want to take a look (at least) at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid::_prepareCollection()`

Comment: $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addOrderedQty()
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); 
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

I want to filter this product collection showing items which are IN Stock, AddInStockFilterCollection works but fails for configurable products, SO they need to be removed by another filter ISSaleable, How can I do that??

Answer (score 4):

This should give you just catalog visible simple products that are in stock.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); // enabled
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
//$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('1234')); //for testing purposes
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
$prodIds = $products->getAllIds();
```

Comment: The addSaleableFilterToCollection function has been marked as deprecated and is an empty stub - it does nothing and as far as I can tell, it never did.

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score -1):

After

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

do

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', TRUE);
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301841/filtering-product-collection-on-is-salable
There is no such filter. I need some way to filter out Configurable products