# Magento : Taking 35 Second to load 4 product's

Tags: magento, caching, nginx

I have created a extension that filters product collection based on a attribute.
Below is the controllers, block and view template code.

**Controller**

```
    $url = Mage::getUrl('no-route');
    if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ajax')){
       echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogextensions/bestsellers_home_list')          
            ->setTemplate('catalog/landings/bestseller.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
    }
    else{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('Besesellers');
    $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

**Block product collection function**

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array( array( 'attribute'=>'top_seller', 'eq' => '1' )));
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
    $products->getSelect()->limit(4,$this->get_cur_page());
    return $products ;
```

Product collection is iterated on view.phtml template.

Now, it is taking 35 seconds to get the output, below are the statistics of execution that i was able to get by making use of PHP's microtime() function

For

1. Block(product collection ) it taking around  **0.01 second**
2. Template Rendering its taking around  **0.12 second**

But for controller function it is taking around **35 second**

I am not able to find what to check, because controller function just create a Block at runtime.

*Note:I am making use of a Paid full page  cache Extension "Mirasvit FPC".

how can i find it what is taking time

Server configuration is

- 30GB Ram with 4 vCPU.
- Application server : Nginx + php5-fpm.
- Version: Magento CE 1.8.0.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use a bit deprecated way to call the filters. I don't know if that can really influate the time of loading but using addFieldToFilter() would limit the calls to database and can be usefull. You can use :

[Magento: Filter products by Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651028/magento-filter-products-by-status)

[filtering product collection on "is_salable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301841/filtering-product-collection-on-is-salable)

The block is maybe not cached correctly. I mean the products are load each time the page is called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your flat product is set to on and all attributes needed for your filters are set as filter.

If a listing comes from EAv tables it might consume lots of resources thus slowing down.

Additionally apply optimization tricks.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you need to add all attributes to select?
You can replace the

```
addAttributeToSelect('*')
```

with

```
addAttributeToSelect(array('attribute_code', 'attribute_code'))
```

Next, what exactly is that

```
$this->get_cur_page()
```

doing? Rest of code shouldn't make disastrous performance issues.

PS
This should have been a comment, but I'm unable to comment yet.